# make all images except one disappear dynamically

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

I'm trying to create an app that has a set of images on screen. when the user clicks an image and then shakes the phone, all the images from the view disappear from the screen except the one he clicked. this is what I wrote up to now:

```
// List of the Images for the app
private ImageView image1, image2;
private ImageView image3, image4;
private ImageView image5, image6;
private ImageView image7, image8;
private ImageView image9, image10;
private ImageView image11, image12;

private ImageView selectedImage;
private boolean flag = true;

// an array that will hold all the images.
private ImageView cards[] = new ImageView[12];

//SET THE IMAGES...


// onShake
mSensorListener
        .setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {
                public void onShake() {
                if (selectedImage != null) {
                    showSelectedImageOnly();
                }
            }
        });

private void showSelectedImageOnly() {
    if(!flag)
        return;

    for (ImageView image : cards){
        if(image.getId() != selectedImage.getId()){
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.d("--MY-APP", "image number "+image.getId()+" was deleted");
        }
    }
    flag = false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ImageView01:
        selectedImage = null;
        selectedImage = image1;
        rotateImage(0, image1, image2);
        defineTrickCard(0);
        break;
    case R.id.ImageView02:
        selectedImage = image1;
        rotateImage(0, image1, image2);
        defineTrickCard(0);
        break;
    case R.id.ImageView03:
    // .... THIS GOES ON...
    case R.id.ImageView12:
        selectedImage = image11;
        rotateImage(5, image11, image12);
        defineTrickCard(5);
        break;
    }
}

private void rotateImage(int index, ImageView firstImage,
        ImageView secondImage) {
    if (isImages[index]) {
        applyRotation(0, 90, firstImage, secondImage, isImages[index]);
        isImages[index] = !isImages[index];

    } else {
        applyRotation(0, -90, firstImage, secondImage, isImages[index]);
        isImages[index] = !isImages[index];
    }
}

private void applyRotation(float start, float end, ImageView firstImage,
        ImageView secondImage, boolean isFirst) {
    // Find the center of image
    final float centerX = firstImage.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    final float centerY = firstImage.getHeight() / 2.0f;

    // Create a new 3D rotation with the supplied parameter
    // The animation listener is used to trigger the next animation
    final Flip3dAnimation rotation = new Flip3dAnimation(start, end,
            centerX, centerY);
    rotation.setDuration(500);
    rotation.setFillAfter(true);
    rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(isFirst, firstImage,
            secondImage));

    if (isFirst) {
        firstImage.startAnimation(rotation);
    } else {
        secondImage.startAnimation(rotation);
    }

}
```

the problem is, that when a user clicks more than one image and after that the phone gets shaked, all the images that got clicked remain on view and the rest disappear as neede.

any thoughts on how to fix this? I have to make all the non-selected (including previous selections) to disappear from screen.

**UPDATE:**

updated the code to show the `rotateImage` function, the rest of the code for the 3D Animation was taken from this [very good tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are using `Animation` to rotate the images in the `rotateImage` method. The point to note in case of animations is that the `View` object is unaltered during the animation. So if you have to set the view to be hidden, you need to register for `onAnimationEnd` event and call `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

Comment: I've been using [this tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html), and it has a transition of images in the end of the rotation.

Comment: Can you please post the code of the `rotateImage` method? You can update your original question.

Comment: Ok, looks like `DisplayNextView` does indeed register for animation callbacks and `SwapView` does make the view `GONE`. Are you sure you have populated `cards[]` with all the 12 images?

Comment: yes, I fixed it, since the rotation changes one image to the other, and my code chose the first image instead of the second one, nothing was showing. changing to a regular `for` loop and showing both `image[i]` and `image[i+1]` did the trick, thanks for the direction pointing